# Change case of parameters, variables, etc using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to find an easy way of implementing naming standards in my ASP.NET MVC project. Essentially, I just want to ensure that parameters are camel case, or something. Is there functionality built into Visual Studio Express or Pro for this purpose, or would I need to view all the source files and update by hand?

UPDATE: As suggested, I'm going with Resharper. Although it costs money, so if anyone's on a budget, CodeRush is free(-ish).

Comment: Maybe use Resharper it has possibility to check whole code for this issues http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetbrains Resharper can help you do this, or at least notify you about correct naming conventions.

Comment: I take it VS doesn't have this built-in? But Resharper is the logical choice, so I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: No, unfortunately VS doesn't have this built in.